# Security rules with dynamic paths

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-authentication

Say I have a database with the following structure:

- Permissions

  - $pId (auto generated id from push)

    - userId
    - roomId
    - permission
- User

  - $uId

    - Name
- Room

  - $rId

    - Name

Is it possible to write a rule that says "allow user to modify room if there exists a permission p where p.userId = auth.uid and p.roomId = $rId and p.permission = 'admin'"?

As far as I can tell it isn't possible without nesting permission information under each room.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to change your structure a bit. Instead of using a push id to identify permissions, use a more controlled structure. For example:

```
"Permissions": {
  "roomId": {
    "userId": "role"
  }
}
```

Now you can secure the room as you want with:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Room": {
      "$rId": {
        ".write": "root.child('Permissions').child($rId).child(auth.Id).val() == 'admin'"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

An added advantage is that you don't have to scan all the permissions if you every want to revoke a user's permission.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  However, it would be more difficult to query "Give me all rooms a user belongs to" as well as "Give me all users in a room".

 Currently I'm using "ref.orderByChild(child).equalTo(value).on" to give me what I want depending on whether it's permissions with user id x or permissions with room id y.

That's inefficient because then I'm getting back a single child at a time due to the way orderByChild works.



Do you think the recommended setup is then PermissionsByUser and PermissionsByRoom as separate but duplicate branches?

Comment: It's a bit hard to parse that as text. But in general when modeling data in NoSQL it is best to model the data in the way your app needs to access it. So if you want to show a list of rooms for user, store the rooms for each user. So don't `ref.child('rooms').orderByChild('userid').equalTo(auth.uid)` but `ref.child('userRooms').child(auth.uid)`. That last one is dead cheap, at the cost of a more duplicated data structure. Dead cheap scales really well. :-) Also see https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html